# How do I serve media files in a local Django environment?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I can upload an image through the admin page, but the image can not be found when I navigate to the url that is generated by django. (404 error)
The files are being uploaded to the folder:

```
project_root/media/eventbanner/1/
```

I have tried multiple solutions but none seem to work for my situation.
Django 1.10 is being run local on Ubuntu 16.04.

The url I get is:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/eventbanner/1/banner_image.jpg
```

Media root folder is located at:

```
/home/username/xxx/xxx/project_name/media
```

Code in HTML file:

```
<div class="banner-image">
  <img src="{{ event.eventbanner.banner_image.url }}"/>
</div>
```

url.py code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'events'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^details/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
url(r'^details/(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/addcomment/$', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
def validate_only_one_instance(obj):
    model = obj.__class__
    if (model.objects.count() > 0 and obj.id != model.objects.get().id):
        raise ValidationError("Can only create 1 %s instance" % model.__name__)

class EventBanner(models.Model):
    event = models.OneToOneField(Event, unique=True)
    banner_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        validate_only_one_instance(self)
```

Comment: For information, this became much simpler with Django 2.0+ : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#static

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The real problem here is that there is no relationship between this url `http://localhost:8000/media/eventbanner/1/banner_image.jpg` and this location on disk `/home/username/xxx/xxx/project_name/media`.

In a production application you'd have a web server where you'd store your `Media` content, the serving URL would be `MEDIA_ROOT` and you'd append `ImageField.url` to this value to get a valid image path.

What you need here is to set up a web server for your media images. At first that sounds like a lot of work, but Django provides a shortcut...

[Serving Files in Development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development)

You have some work you need to do to have the media files served locally. It requires some changes to your `urls.py` ...

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

This uses the `views.serve` bit and should only be used in `DEBUG` mode. It overrides the path to media files(django's term for user uploaded content like `ImageField`). This will redirect those requests through the `serve` view. Best I can tell this is a mini web server that will map those request routes to locations on disk and allow those locations to be reachable via HTTP urls.

Answer (score 9):

As of at least Django 1.8, there is a [helper function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) `static()` that will set this up for you and ensure that it only functions in debug mode.

Your `urls.py` should look something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

...to simply quote the documentation.

Make sure that your `MEDIA_URL` is set to a relative path like `/media/` and that your `MEDIA_ROOT` is an absolute filesystem path like `/home/foo/project/media`.